# how to pass json format as one argument in spark submit?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, command-line-arguments, spark-submit

```
 spark-submit --class com.HelloWorld \
--master yarn --deploy-mode client \
--executor-memory 5g  /home/Hadoop-Work/HelloWorld.jar \
"/home/Hadoop-Work/application.properties" \
"Student_db,stud_info_table,ClassA,\"[\"{\"system\":\"stud_info_table|student_name\",\"actual\":\"stud_info_table|student_phone\",\"class_strength\":\"50\"}\"]\",DepartmentA,120"
```

Here `arg(0)` is  `/home/Hadoop-Work/application.properties`

`arg(1)` is  `"Student_db,stud_info_table,ClassA,\"[\"{\"system\":\"stud_info_table|student_name\",\"actual\":\"stud_info_table|student_phone\",\"class_strength\":\"50\"}\"]\",DepartmentA,120"`

```scala
object HelloWorld {

   def main(args: Array[String]){

    val input =args(1)
    val splited = input.split(",")
    val dbname = splited(0)
    val tablename = splited(1)
    val classname = splited(2)
    val jsonInputColumns = splited(3) // here I want json format as one argument ----> "[{system:stud_info_table|student_name,actual:stud_info_table|student_phone,class_strength:50}]"
    val departmentName = splited(4)
    val kafka_timeout_sec = splited(5)      
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you had try the solution I suggested? If it does not work, can you specify where it does not? If yes, can you accept the answer to close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are splitting on the comma separator, which is also present in your json. A workaround is to use another, * not common * separator, such as `;;`

I made it work by changing your code to

```
  object HelloWorld {

   def main(args: Array[String]){

    val input =args(1)
    val splited = input.split(";;")
    val dbname = splited(0)
    val tablename = splited(1)
    val classname = splited(2)
    val jsonInputColumns = splited(3) // here I want json format as one argument ----> "[{system:stud_info_table|student_name,actual:stud_info_table|student_phone,class_strength:50}]"
    val departmentName = splited(4)
    val kafka_timeout_sec = splited(5)      
    }

   }
```

and your arguments to `"Student_db;;stud_info_table;;ClassA;;\"[\"{\"system\":\"stud_info_table|student_name\",\"actual\":\"stud_info_table|student_phone\",\"class_strength\":\"50\"}\"]\";;DepartmentA;;120"`

Comment: Is `input.split(",")` correct ? I think input will be split on `;;`